# QSqlTableModel empty result

Tags: mysql, qt, qt4

If I do this:

```
QSqlQuery searchQuery(QString("select * from people where id = %1").arg(1));
if (searchQuery.next())
  {
  std::cout << "Name: " << searchQuery.value(1).toString().toStdString() << std::endl;
  }
```

The output is (as expected):

```
Name: David
```

However, if I do this:

```
 QSqlTableModel *model = new QSqlTableModel;
    // Set used table
    model->setTable("people");
    model->setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel::OnManualSubmit);
// Set where clause
model->setFilter(QString("id=%1").arg(1));
model->select();

// Read result
QSqlRecord record = model->record();
if (!record.isEmpty())
  {
  std::cout << "Name from model: " << record.value(1).toString().toStdString();
  }
```

The record is not empty, but the output is blank:

```
Name from model:
```

Can anyone see what have I done wrong using the QSqlTableModel?

Also, with both methods, I don't understand how you don't have to tell it which database to use (i.e. I instantiate a QSqlDatabase and .open() it, but I never tell the query to operate on the database?)

Thanks,

David

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
QSqlRecord record = model->record();
```

You are using [QSqlQueryModel::record()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qsqlquerymodel.html#record-2) which returns a "blank" record, instead of QSqlQueryModel::record(int row). The record you are getting is not empty : you can get the number and name of fields returned by the query from it.

With QSqlQuery or QSqlTableModel, you can specify which database connection to use (see QSqlTableModel or QSqlQuery constructors). If you don't, then the default database connection is used : see [QSqlDatabase documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qsqldatabase.html#details). If you didn't explicitly gave it a name, the connection you opened is the default connection.